# UniqueID optimized for android device

Tags: java, android

I am trying to generate a unique id for android phones and tablets. I found an interesting function but with my brand new galaxy tab 2 it does not work. Here is my function :

```
public String generateId(TelephonyManager tm, ContentResolver resolver) {
    final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
    tmDevice  = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
    tmSerial  = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    androidId = "" + Secure.getString(resolver, Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
    return deviceUuid.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply use the phone's milisecond timestamp, convert it to a string and append the hex representation of a random number between 0 and 10000 (and generate it + store it in shared Prefs when the app runs the first time).
Eg : 1342603520897_1bf

If you expect thousands of installs per millisecond, this won't work. If not, it's fine.

The drawback to this solution is that it's not persisted across installs but it does give you an anonymous id which may be a plus.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I know it is not easy but I am looking for a persistent solution. The above function should work for galaxy tab 2. At least device id and android id should not be an empty string...

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that if your user changes carriers, he will change SIM and you will have a different ID and not match him to the previous one. That would happen even if he just took out the SIM card.

Comment: Yes absolutely, it is true for a phone. If it is a tablet, sim equals null but I still do not understand how the returned value could be empty on galaxy tab... It works for all phones.

Comment: On some tablets, SIM is not null. They could have a data plan for it or just be on vacation and switch their phone SIM into the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

OK here is a working solution. Not as elegant as the previous one... but it works.

```
public String generateId(TelephonyManager tm, WifiInfo wi, ContentResolver resolver) {
    String m_szImei = "";
    String m_szDevIDShort = "";
    String m_szAndroidID = "";
    String m_szSim = "";
    String uniqueId = "";
    //imei
    try {
        m_szImei = tm!=null ? tm.getDeviceId() : "";
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    //sim
    try {
        m_szSim = tm!=null && new Checker().isSim(tm) ? tm.getSimSerialNumber() : wi!=null ? wi.getMacAddress() : "";
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    //"fake" imei for tablets
    try {
        m_szDevIDShort = "35" + //we make this look like a valid IMEI
            Build.BOARD.length()%10+ Build.BRAND.length()%10 +
            Build.CPU_ABI.length()%10 + Build.DEVICE.length()%10 +
            Build.DISPLAY.length()%10 + Build.HOST.length()%10 +
            Build.ID.length()%10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length()%10 +
            Build.MODEL.length()%10 + Build.PRODUCT.length()%10 +
            Build.TAGS.length()%10 + Build.TYPE.length()%10 +
            Build.USER.length()%10 ; //13 digits
    } catch(Exception e) {}
    //android id (may be null)
    m_szAndroidID = Secure.getString(resolver, Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    //unique id
    try {
        uniqueId = SHA256.compute(m_szImei+m_szSim+m_szDevIDShort+m_szAndroidID);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return uniqueId;
}
```

Comment: SHA256 is a user class (compute() is static)

Answer (score 0):

Try: `String secureId = Secure.ANDROID_ID;` 
More: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

It's a 64-bit hash assigned to device for it's lifetime (or factory reset, new ROM etc).

-- edit --

```
// usage:
Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID));
```

-- edit2 --

```
String id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID));
if(id==null || id=="9774d56d682e549c") { // emulator id
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)Ctxt.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    id = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
}
```

-- edit3 --

Here's the solution [proposed by Google](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html) itself. In other words, generate hash at app first run and store it permanently :).

Comment: Hi, yes I use correctly it in my 2 solutions. (It returns null in my new android galaxy tab 2).

Comment: How unique should it be? I mean, how about using mac address only in case when ANDROID_ID returned null? I suggest it, only because it will be easiest to implement :) Look @ edit2.

Comment: Or rather, how consistent id's you need?

Comment: The mac address is null in galaxy tab 2, and should be null if wifi is turned off. That is why I generate a "fake IMEI". The id should be as unique as possible. I use it to remember users so that they do not have to input login/password every time they open my app.

Comment: I just added 3rd edit which is a way suggested by Google (yeah, with code samples :). Hope it'll help!